# how to run the command "ps -eo pid,user,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%cpu | head" through python

Tags: python, linux

I want to run the command `ps -eo pid,user,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%cpu | head` to get the output through a python script.

I tried making it with the subprocess library but i am not able to find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include an example you tried.

You should be able to use the subprocess module in Python to run the ps command and capture its output:

```
import subprocess

def get_top_processes():
    result = subprocess.run(['ps', '-eo', 'pid,user,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu', '--sort=-%cpu', '|', 'head'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return result.stdout.decode('utf-8')

top_processes = get_top_processes()
print(top_processes)
```

In this code, `subprocess.run` is used to run the `ps` command, and `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` is used to capture the standard output of the command. The `result.stdout` is then decoded to a string, and the resulting string is returned from the `get_top_processes` function.